# Windows не меняет программу по умолчанию для файлов .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, idle

Переустановил питон, записал все нужное в переменную PATH

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Папку со своими скриптами закинул в папку с питоном(как и было до этого), так же прописал её в переменной PATH чтобы можно было через cmd запускать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по какой то причине windows не видит расширения `.py` у скриптов, то есть не открывает файлы с помощью python.exe открывал через пкм и вручную выбирал программу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после выбора `python.exe` ничего не происходило, не не менялась программа запуска по умолчанию, не появлялась в рекомендуемых программах запуска, через IDLE все скрипты запускаются и работают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В программах по умолчанию указан Notepad++ при попытке изменить и указать python.exe повторяется история что я указал выше

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь гугл излазил не нашел решения, знает кто в чем дело?

Comment: На предпоследнем скрине нажмите "Обзор" и укажите, где находится python.exe

Comment: @V-Mor На предпоследнем скрине я это уже сделал, смотрите скрины выше, я прожал `обзор`, нашел файл `python.exe` прожал `открыть`

Comment: Переменная окружения называется `PATH` (от англ. _путь_), а не `PATCH` (от англ. _латать, заплатка_)

Comment: А самый банальный вариант еще раз переустановить? Заодно при установке он сам и подцепит все ассоциации. Перед установкой снести все лишнее. Как то был подобный лаг на только что установленной версии, после повторной переустановки все ок.

Comment: @Kers Все что можно переустанавливал, решение уже нашел, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, вдруг пригодится кому, через реестр можно поправить ассоциацию файлов, переходим по пути в реестре `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`→`Software`→`Microsoft`→`Windows`→`CurrentVersion`→`Explorer`→`FileExts`→`.py` и удаляем папку `UserChoice`, видимо после этого сбрасывается значение по умолчанию и можно выбрать его заново

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте, что именно у вас установлено в качестве приложения по умлочанию. Сделать это можно в окне "Выбор стандартных приложений для типов файлов".

Открыть данное окно можно следующим образом (описано для **Windows 10**):

1. Запустите "Панель управления"
2. Далее "Программы" > "Программы по умолчаю" > "Сопоставление типов файлов или протоколов с конкретными программами"

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В появившемся окне "Приложения по умолчанию" проскрольте в самый низ и выберите пункт "Выбор стандартных приложений для типов файлов".

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. В появившемся окне найдите типы файлов, начинающиеся с ".py" и выбирайте для них приложения.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Если не помогло**, то придется удалять ассоциацию приложения и типа файла вручную.

1. Запустите Редактор реестра: введите команду `regedit.exe` в командной строке или окне "Выполнить"
2. В дереве слева найдите ветку `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.py`. если есть возможность - раскройте ее
3. Выделите подветку "OpenWithProgids", нажмите на ней ПКМ, выберите пункт "Удалить". На рисунке я показал это для расширения `.pyw`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Проверьте, что ассоциация с другой программой пропала. В этом случае, должна быть выбрана программа, зарегестрировавшая данное расширение - это именно интерпретатор python

Comment: Исправил вопрос, добавил скрин и описание

Comment: А для `.pyc` или `.pyw` файла вы можете указать приложением `python.exe`? А удалить эту строчку из таблицы? Какие варианты указанное в тексте вопроса окно показывает по ПКМ на строке? (у меня другая версия системы и я не помню, как это окно работало раньше)

Comment: Вижу только расширения `.pyz` и `.pyzw` для них уже указанно приложение python.exe

Comment: Все варианты `Рекомендуемых программ` указанны на скрине и они не меняются даже если укажу вручную файл python.exe, все программы что находятся в `Другие программы` не являются приложениям python

Comment: строчек `.pyc` или `.pyw` нет

Comment: Попробуй выбрать вообще любую другую программу. Например блокнот. А потом еще раз попробовать выбрать `python.exe` Иногда бывает залипание странное, но через другую программу может получится разлочить эту запись.

Comment: Попробовал не помогло

Comment: Дополнил ответ редактированием реестра

Comment: Не вижу чтобы ответ изменился

Comment: Значит, скорее всего, расширение зарегестрировано np++, что странно. Могу только посоветовать удалить np++, удалить python, запустить какой-нибудь очиститель реестра, затем установить python заново